# iPhone Application submission queries

Tags: iphone

I have few queries regarding iPhone app submission.

1) I have an account and want to make my application available for US.(I have seen the options which allows to select the countries in submission process document). So is it possible to show my application to US users with my india account.

2) I want to show the different names for  Seller and copyrights. In future If I submit another app, I should be able to show the same seller name but copy rights name will be changed. So is it possible to show in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Malleswar

Comment: Yeah, that is highly demotivating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, it's possible.
2) You can only choose Seller name once (At the time of your first app submission). The copyright info should be submitted with every app you submit.